# can not Impersonate the permission in the NamedPipes if client and server are in the different machines

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation, named-pipes

I got the UnknownErrorException with error code 1346 for named pipe, the code as below
(notes: the client and server are in different machines)

server code:

```
public static void ReadFile()
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\123.txt");   <-- exception
}

public static void Main()
{    
    var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut);
    while (true)
    {
        pipe.WaitForConnection();
        pipe.RunAsClient(ReadFile);
    }
}
```

client code

```
 NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
                new NamedPipeClientStream("\\jachang-w1", "testpipe",
                    PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
                    TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);
 pipeClient.Connect();
```

I have search the info from google, and found the error is  "ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid"

but I have set TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation in the client, so server should be able access it. could someone tell me what wrong it is? and how should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a domain user or are they two local users (one on each non-domain computer) with the same login and password?

Comment: both server and client are loged on by domain user. and I can read d:\123.txt if I logon the server and open directly. and the code does work if the client ran on the jachang-w1 too.

Comment: And client and server were login by same domain user account. (Sorry, forgot to mention that...)

Answer (score 3):

In order for the server process to impersonate the client with the token impersonation level `Impersonate`, its own process identity must have the security privilege `SeImpersonatePrivilege`, and this privilege must be enabled.

This is true even if the client and server account identities are the same domain account.

I guess that the domain account you are testing with does not have this privilege, or does not have it enabled. When you call `RunAsClient`, a thread token will be created, but this will not be granted the requested impersonation level because the process lacks the required privilege: the level will 'downgrade' to `Identification`. Then, when the call to `ReadAllText` is made, somewhere within the implementation of this method the Windows security APIs will be used to check the thread token against the file's access control list. The token will be found not to have the required impersonation level to succeed in reading the file, and the error you have seen will be raised.

To solve the problem you will have to find some way of ensuring that your server process runs with an identity which has the required privilege.